# Firebase: How to access error message in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image: Screenshot of error response]

I'm using Firebase as a simple backend for my project. Lately I've found that Firebase will expire my token after a short period of time, so I want to catch this exact error and make the user login again.

The problem is, Firebase gives me a weird object for an error response, and I don't know how I can reach the error message property "Auth token is expired". I tried something like this to no avail:

```
this.dataService.sendData(data)
  .subscribe(
    (response) => console.log(response),
    (error) => {
        if(error._body.error == "Auth token is expired"){
          //make user login
        }
      }
  );
```

Comment: I think `error` most response with a status code. i recommend use the if statement with that code

Comment: Are you familiar with Firebase? I wasn't able to find the corresponding error code for "Auth token is expired". Can you figure it out from the screenshot?

Comment: `error` object response with a code and message. you'd see it in the console or in the network `request` xhr.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that error responses come in the form of objects with properties of a code and message. The problem is I can't figure out how to access these properties when it comes to Firebase's specific error response. Please look at my screenshot.

Comment: just type `error.status`. Remember, `error` is the main object and there is inside the `status`. for this Response properties, you can use `status`

Comment: Okay I wasn't aware that Http codes are the same for any type of backend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, you can access `status` code.

```
const TOKEN_AUTH_EXPIRED: number = 401;

this.dataService.sendData(data)
  .subscribe(
    (response) => console.log(response),
    (error: any) => {
        if(error.status  == TOKEN_AUTH_EXPIRED){
          //make user login
        }
      }
  );
```